# Controlling height expansion in a row flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am very confused about flex boxes. Here's the layout I have right now:

[image]

And the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        /* flex boxes */
        .interblock{background:gray;height:100%;display:flex;flex-flow:row wrap;}
        .subrect{flex:1 90%;}
        .labelrect{flex:0 1 10%;}
        .footrect{flex:1 100%;background:yellow;height:auto;}
        .topleft{flex:0 1 50%;height:auto;background:green;}
        .topright{flex:0 1 50%;height:auto;background:red;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='interblock'>
        <div class='topleft'>
            topleft
        </div>    
        <div class='topright'>
            topright
        </div>
        <div class='labelrect' style='background:coral'>labelrect</div>
        <div class='subrect' style="background:orange">subrect</div>    
        <div class='labelrect' style='background:cyan'>labelrect</div>
        <div class='subrect' style="background:blue">subrect</div>      
        <div class='footrect'>
            footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This layout is almost correct. The problem is that I want the center block of subrects/labelrects to use 100% of the height that is not being used by the header and footer. There could be an arbitrary number of subrects/labelrects and they should all have the same height. I'm not sure how to specify an expanding height that takes into account the content of the header and footer. How can I get the labelrect/subrect block to be height 100% - header - footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter your markup some. Here I created 2 wrappers, 1 for your `top` and 1 for the `middle`.

Giving the `top` and `footrect` `flex: 0` make them size by content and `middle` having `flex: 1` to fill the rest of the space.

```css
/* flex boxes */

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.interblock {
  background: gray;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top,
.footrect {
  flex: 0;
}
.top {
  flex-basis: auto;
  display: flex;
}
.middle {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.subrect {
  flex: 1 90%;
}
.labelrect {
  flex: 0 1 10%;
}
.footrect {
  background: yellow;
}
.topleft {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}
.topright {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='interblock'>
  <div class='top'>
    <div class='topleft'>
      topleft<br><br>
    </div>
    <div class='topright'>
      topright
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='middle'>
    <div class='labelrect' style='background:coral'>labelrect</div>
    <div class='subrect' style="background:orange">subrect</div>
    <div class='labelrect' style='background:cyan'>labelrect</div>
    <div class='subrect' style="background:blue">subrect</div>
  </div>
  <div class='footrect'>
    footer<br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```